# How to share configuration variables in Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

I'm new to JavaScript/Nodejs. How can I share my configuration across the Nodejs application. For example: I have a `config/config.coffee`

```
path = require("path")

module.exports = {
  development:
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/hello'
    root: rootPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
}
```

I included `config.coffee` in my `app.coffee`.

```
express = require("express")

# Load configurations
env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
config = require("./config/config")[env]

require('./config/boot')

app = express()
```

Now I want to include `config` variable into my `config/boot.coffee`. How can I do it? I don't want to re-include `config/config.coffee` into `config/boot.coffee`. Here is the my `config/boot.coffee` file:

```
env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
config = require("./config")[env]
fs = require("fs")
mongo = require("mongoose")

# Bootstrap db connections
mongo.connect config.db

# Bootstrap models
models_path = config.root+"/app/models"
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach( (file)->
  require(models_path + '/' + file) if ~file.indexOf('.coffee')
)

# Bootstrap services
services_path = config.root+"/app/services"
fs.readdirSync(services_path).forEach( (file)->
  require(models_path + '/' + file) if ~file.indexOf('_service.coffee')
)
```

Sorry for bad English :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out [nconf](https://github.com/flatiron/nconf), which helps you keep a kind of "waterfall" approach to application configuration, which allows you to mix your configuration from different sources very transparently.

You can see nconf in action in this project I wrote, [unbox](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox), which is basically boilerplate I use for applications I write on Node. You can check out how configuration is loaded [here](https://github.com/bevacqua/unbox/blob/master/env/index.js).

You could use something like [grunt-pemcrypt](https://github.com/bevacqua/grunt-pemcrypt) for increased security by checking in the secure, encrypted file, and saving the encryption key somewhere safe.

[12factor](http://12factor.net/config) also has a nice approach to application configuration you might want to look into.

Answer (score 2):

I believe NodeJS caches your `require`'s, so calling `require('config')` again won't cause any performance degradation.

http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_require

Comment: @Zeck You can create a conf.js, that does: `var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'; module.exports = require("./config")[env];` Then `require('conf')` wherever you're using it.